# Airflow: Retry task in DAG only if task returns a particular exit code

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an airflow DAG running multiple BashOperator tasks. These tasks in turn call an API which submits jobs on EMR clusters. The API returns a different exit code based on whether EMR job has succeeded (0), failed (1) or timed out(124). Only the timed out tasks should be retried by airflow.

Is it possible to have a callback function on error which will capture the exit code and re-trigger the task? If not then can this be handled by some existing functionality that I have missed?

== Edit 1 ==
Did some digging in airflow source and found this:

`if sp.returncode:
                    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")`

This indicates that unless exit code is 0, airflow will mark the task as failed for all other exit codes. Essentially, for any exit code other that 0, airflow will retry the task on the basis of retry value configured.

Also, if I add the logic in call back on_error for retrying based on error_code, I will not have a control on how many times the task is retried.

Comment: Nope. Had to add retries to the API instead.

Comment: @tobi6 Do you have any alternative solution in mind? Airflow way?

Comment: For what? Still don't exactly know what your problem is, after the edit it seems to be resolved.